# Where to host Windows Workflow Foundation engine?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

Is there any guideline to make the decision where to host WF: in our own custom windows NT service or inside IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the option of 3 different runtimes, WorkflowInvoker, WorkflowApplication and WorkflowServiceHost. In the last case the AppFabrik running on IIS/WAS is a generic host you can use. In general that would be a good choice when doing worklfow services.